Circle area by integral definition
I'm trying to calculate the area of ​​the circle by integral definition. I know that this can be done using triangles to find cicle area, but I'm trying to understand this anyway. So, this is what I've done:
\begin{equation}x_i=0+\frac{i}{n}\hspace{2cm}f(x_i)=\sqrt{r^2-\Big(\frac{i}{n}\Big)^2}\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\int_{0}^r\sqrt{r^2-x^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Delta x=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{r^2-\Big(\frac{i}{n}\Big)^2}\cdot\frac{r}{n}\\=r^2\cdot\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sqrt{r^2-\cos^2\Big(\frac{\pi i}{2n}\Big)}\end{equation}
There is a problem with the last limit, I tried to do it by substitution, but it is not correct. Can anyone help me with this?

If $x_i=\frac{i}{n}$, then you only go from $0$ to $1$, not from $0$ to $r$. Shouldn't $x_i$ be $\frac{ri}{n}$ ?

@Masd is correct. You can apply the same method to prove the formula for volume of a sphere. $$V=\int_{0}^{r} 4πx^2 dx = \frac{4}{3} π r^3 $$(note that surface area of a sphere has formula $4πr^2$)

@ArturoMagidin you're right, I didn't pay attention to that.

@Masd I understand these integrals and they make sense for me. I don't know what to do with this:
\begin{equation}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{r^2-\Big(\frac{ri}{n}\Big)^2}\cdot\frac{r}{n}\end{equation}

I wouldn't do it like that. It's much easier to calculate:
$$\iint_\Omega dxdy$$
Where $\Omega = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2 : x^2 + y^2 \le r^2\}$. Here you shall switch to polar coordinates.
However, if you really want to solve that integral, trig substitution is the answer:
$$\frac A4 = \int_0^r\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\,dx = \int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{r^2 - r^2\sin^2u}\ d(r\sin u) = r^2\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^2 u\,du$$
Where I substituted $x=r\sin u$. Trivial from here.
Another way to do this is proving that the circumference equals $2\pi r$ first:
$$C(r) = 2\int_{-r}^r\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\,dx$$
And then calculating the area this way:
$$A = \int_0^r C(x)\,dx = \int_0^r2\pi x\,dx$$
